# Android: How do I restore WebView contents after my Activity restarts?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview

Does anyone know how to save and restore the content of a `WebView` in Android across phone calls, device rotations and the like? I have the following in an app and it is not restoring any changes to app content. The `WebView` contains JavaScript code that responds to button clicks by modifying the text displayed, but Android is just restoring the original state of the display as set by `mWebView.loadData()`.

The following goes inside my `Activity` class:

```
    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "restoring instance state...");
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState);
        mWebView.restoreState(savedState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "saving instance state...");
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service , and inside it post any change in the webview to this service, and when scrivity restart, restart the webview and add content from the service. Thats all you need.

Comment: I was hoping for something simpler than that.

Comment: It is simple , you just create a class with public static and you just read and right webview data in it, and there couldn't be simpler way since the activity is being closed then opened and thus all its data or variables will be cleared. So the only way is to store the webview data in an external place and then get them. Or you could launch an event containg the webview data and then get them from event after activity restart but as i know it is bad to send data using events.